# Xamarin Forms ConverterParameter - how to reference to current item property?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the object below:

```
public class MyObj {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public double Weight {get; set;}
}
```

I create an ObservableCollection of objects from this class and assign it to ItemsResource of a ListView (lvMyObjs below). I also have an entry.

I need to do the following for each row in my ListView

- Get the value from the entry and pass it to a converter
- Multiply the entry value with the Weight property of current item in the converter
- Show the value in the corresponding row in my listview.

In XAML I have this:

```
<Entry x:Name="entSourceValue"/>
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <local:SourceToTargetConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="lvMyObjs">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ContentView>
            <Frame>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Label x:Name="lblResult"
                    Text="{
                          Binding Text,                            
                          Converter={StaticResource myConverter},
                          ConverterParameter={},
                          Source={x:Reference entSourceValue}
                          }"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
          </ContentView>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In my converter I have this:

```
 public class SourceToTargetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {                     
        double sourceDouble;
        double.TryParse((string)value, out sourceDouble);
        //todo: convert parameter to double 
        //double weight = 

        return sourceDouble * weight;

    }
}
```

I can get the value of my entry in the converter, without any problems. My question is how can I send the "Weight" of current item in the listview as a parameter to the converter? In other words,  what should I put in the line 
"ConverterParameter={},"?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass `MyObj` into the converter and then use the `x:Reference` for your `Entry` as the parameter.

```
<Label x:Name="lblResult" Text="{Binding Path=. ,                            
                      Converter={StaticResource myConverter},
                      ConverterParameter={x:Reference entSourceValue}
                      }"/>
```

And then

```
public class SourceToTargetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {                     
        return ((MyObj)value).Weight * (double)((Entry)parameter).Text;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this. Add your own type checks but that should hopefully help you out.

Comment: When I debug with your code, I get a hit to Converter method when I start the app in the simulator. But nothing happens when I enter something to the Entry and I don't even come to the Converter method.

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper You will need to raise a property changed event for the list object for the converter to run again.